# YUIDoc syntax for optionally static constructor

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, formatting, constructor, static

In JavaScript, I wrote a class that can be optionally instantiated with the `new` keyword, but can also be called statically as well. What is the best way to demonstrate this behavior in comment syntax? I was thinking something like this:

```
// localize constant
var PI = Math.PI;

/**
 * Complex constructor
 * optionally instantiate with `new`
 *
 * @class Complex
 * @constructor
 * @static
 * @param r {Number} real part
 * @param i {Number} imaginary part
 * @param m {Number} optional, magnitude
 * @param t {Number} optional, argument
 * @return {Object} complex number
 */

function Complex(r, i, m, t) {
    if (!(this instanceof Complex)) {
        return new Complex(r, i, m, t);
    }

    if (typeof m === 'number') {
        this.m = Math.abs(m);
    } else {
        this.m = Math.sqrt(r * r + i * i);
    }

    if (typeof t === 'number') {
        this.t = (m >= 0 ? t : t + PI);
    } else {
        this.t = Math.atan2(i, r);
    }

    // limit argument between (-pi,pi]
    this.t = PI - (PI * 3 - (PI - (PI * 3 - this.t) % (PI * 2))) % (PI * 2);
    this.r = r;
    this.i = i;
}
```

Comment: Can't you use words instead of `r, i, m, t`

Comment: @Bhathiya I suppose I could but they're referenced 100s of times in the file so it saves a lot of typing.

Comment: You can start with names like that and then refactor to proper ones.

Answer (score 2):

## Naming

As [Bhathiya](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/47826/bhathiya) pointed out, you should be using actual, descriptive variable names rather than just a single character.

A descriptive variable name means everything, as it increases readability and understanding 10-fold, even if it means typing a few more characters each time you write the variable name.

And, if you really, really don't want to type out a full variable name each time, most text editors or IDEs come with auto-complete. This could help you type less.

---

I think that the best way to express that the class can be instantiated in comment form would be to write something like this:

```
@instantiate: (new) Complex(r, i, m, t);
```

Then, in your code, I recommend adding a comment to these lines:

```
if (!(this instanceof Complex)) {
    return new Complex(r, i, m, t);
}
```

That says that those lines allow for the object to be instantiated with `new`.

However, do you really need both options? Is there something in the full program that you are using that blocks you from using `new`? I can't think of any case where you would be blocked by using `new`, I think you should always use it because it is then very clear that `Complex` is a class.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I apologize. I did not think I could give you a strong answer to your direct question, so I gave a short review on something that I noticed on your code. I did not intend for this to be your best answer; I just wanted to point something out. If you'd like, I could delete this answer.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I edited my answer. Does this answer your question, now?

Comment: I also have a static function called `Complex.Polar()` that requires `new` to be omitted. Making it optional for `Complex()` allows other developers using the library to remain consistent by omitting `new` for both constructors, and saving them the confusion of having to explain why one constructor uses `new` and the other doesn't.